# UserWarning: failed to import the optional _tifffile C extension module

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

When I run code like this in an Ubuntu Pycharm project with

```
import tifffile
first_image = tifffile.imread("first.tif")
```

I get the warning

```
/home/gradescan/PSTraining/tifffile.py:156: UserWarning: failed to import the 
optional _tifffile C extension module.
Loading of some compressed images will be slow.
Tifffile.c can be obtained at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/
  "failed to import the optional _tifffile C extension module.\n"
```

How do I eliminate this warning?  Better, how do I incorporate the _tifffile C extension into my PyCharm project?

If this is duplicated, please don't close because searching on the title which is the error message gives me (and others) nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download tifffile from https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/

```
pip install tifffile

python setup_tifffile_c.py build_ext --inplace
```